# How to install TAdoConnection in delphi XE2 starter?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I just bought Delphi XE2 starter and want to upgrade my projects. One of them is failing because Delphi doesn't know what TAdoConnection is.

I stupidly didn't keep a copy of the package when I D/Led it a few years ago now can't remember where I cgot it from

How to install TAdoCOnnection et al into Delphi XE2?  Thanks

---

Update: alas, I have the Starter edition (who can afford anything else?)

---

Later update, just in case anyone else wants to do some database stuff with a starter edition.

I paid for AnyDac and was very happy, but then it was bought by Embarcadero, so you can't purchase it separately any more. I have a bug with Sqlite, so am looking for alternates.

Start here http://www.freebyte.com/programming/delphi/#freedelphidatabasecompone
ZeosLib looks very promising http://zeoslib.sourceforge.net/portal.php

Comment: It should be there, under ADODB"... as long as you don't have the (crippled!) starter edition :)  PS: I had the same experience with "Turbo Delphi" a few years ago.  Free ... but useless.

Comment: Yes, I have the starte edition. But iirc it wasn't included with D7 either & I D/Led from somwhere & installed it. I would like to do the same with XE2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes with Delphi, as long as you don't just have the "starter" edition, so you should already have it installed. Look in the ADODB unit. There is no other package to download.

Comment: You can check the [feature matrix](http://www.embarcadero.com/delphi-features-matrix) (PDF) to see what else you're missing from the "real" versions.

Comment: +1 Thanks Rob. Do you know how I can get my ADO reliant projects to work with XE2?

Comment: @Mawg: There are only three possibilities: 1) upgrade to a version of XE2 that includes ADO, 2) import the ADO type libraries and use them to write your own replacement for the ADO components, or 3) switch to a new component set like Zeos and do the necessary code rewrites.

Comment: +1 Rob (and Ken).  Rob, here in Asia even an upgrade from starter to Pro at "Special offer" prices until end of Dec 2011 is US $1k  :-(

Comment: Wah!   upgrade starter to pro in USA - D/L only = US $7999.  Same thing in S.E. Asia = US $1,039 plus sales tax.   I can only imagine that teh extra $240 is because the elctrons have to travel farther.

Comment: Rob, you seem to know more than most.  Is my understanding of the feature matrix correct? Starter means I have to migrate existing code to Interbase (how good is that? I do see praise online); pro only adds MySql using dbExpress, which might mean code change anyway; enterrpise gives me full ODBC, which is what ADOB/TAdoConnection was offering - is that correct?  So, I can go all Interbase for free, or if I must have ODBC can find a FOSS package or a commerical which costs leass than XE2 enterprise?  If you can confrm/correct/exapnd, then you get awarded the answer. Thanks!

Comment: It's $1000 in Asia? It's only $500 in the United States. I don't know why it's so different. Maybe you can order it through the U.S. store instead. I doubt the starter-to-pro price is $8000, or even $800. Eight hundred is the price for a *new* pro license; it's $500 to upgrade to Delphi XE2 pro from *any* prior version, so just pretend you don't already have the starter version and order the pro upgrade. Maybe there's even still time to get a refund on the starter version.

Comment: I don't actually know much about the database products at all. I just read the feature matrix. The only Delphi-provided database components I've ever used are the IBX components for connecting to Firebird, and that was with Delphi 2005. I've also never used anything above the professional edition, so I don't know what all the higher-level database offerings really mean.

Answer (score 1):

It should be there, under ADODB:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ADODB

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ADODB.TADOConnection

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeSamples/en/ADOQuery_%28Delphi%29

ADDENDUM:

Here's the XE2 feature matrix:

http://www.embarcadero.com/images/Delphi/delphi_short_feature_matrix_large.png

ADO is available on all versions ... EXCEPT the "starter version".

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find a donwload link there, just documentation. If I overlooked it, can you point me at it? Thanks.

Comment: @Mawg: Read the **last line** of this answer carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the Starter version, there is no direct option for TADOConnection.  You either upgrade your version of Delphi, or use something other than TADOConnection.