# "class TADOConnection not found." in fresh install of delphi xe2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Installed a fresh Delphi xe2.

Open a new project (vcl forms application). opened the pallets and looked for TADOConnection, there is no such component.

Tired to repair the Delphi xe2 installation. no change.

Any way To resolve this?

Comment: What edition are you using? Note that Starter edition does not include  dbGO (ADO) components.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600295/how-to-install-tadoconnection

Comment: You can verify it in the About box [`here`](http://img804.imageshack.us/img804/9795/84780445.png).

Comment: Perhaps your Library Path is not set correctly? (Unless you're using Starter edition). Also perhaps you unchecked the dbGO/ADO checkbox during the installation?

Comment: @WarrenP please write your comment as answer, so i could accept it. solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your Library Path is not set correctly? (Unless you're using Starter edition). Also perhaps you unchecked the dbGO/ADO checkbox during the installation?